# Where does Windows store DNS entry list?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-10

If I go to network adapters, right click, properties, IPV4, "use dns" and enter some addresses, where does Windows store it?

[image: dns entry list]

Does it store in the registry? Some physical file? Is it possible to edit the entries without opening all those windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are stored in the registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`

`NameServer` is/are the value(s).

You can use Powershell to set these values:

`Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 12 -ServerAddresses ("10.0.0.1","10.0.0.2")`